# Obtain data from the $scope

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-repeat

First off I'd like to say that I'm just starting with AngularJS, so please excuse me if this is a stupid question.

I have a controller that performs an AJAX request and it returns a JSON object. This JSON is then saved as `$scope.person`. It look's like this:

```js
function PersonController($scope, $http) {
  $http({
    method: 'GET',
    url: constants.adminUrl + '/getJSON.php?data=person'
  }).success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
    $scope.person = data;
  }).error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
    throw new Error('I\'m truly sorry, but I couldn\'t fetch your data');
  });
}
```

The file `getJSON.php` successfully returns what I expect, a JSON object which looks like this:

```js
[{
  "id": 1,
  "firstName": "Silvestre",
  "lastName": "Herrera",
  "headline": "Diseñador y front-end engineer",
  "location": "Argentina",
  "summary": "Summary summary summary"
}]
```

And then, in my HTML I have the following:

```html
<ol ng-controller="PersonController">
  <li ng-repeat="person in person | filter: {id:1}">
      <input data-autoGrow name="firstName" type="text" value="{{ person.firstName }}" placeholder="<?= __("What's your first name?"); ?>"><input data-autoGrow name="lastName" type="text" value="{{ person.lastName }}" placeholder="<?= __("And your last name?"); ?>">
  </li>
  <li ng-repeat="person in person | filter: {id:1}"><input type="text" value="{{ person.headline }}" placeholder="<?= __("Headline"); ?>"></li>
  <li ng-repeat="person in person | filter: {id:1}"><input type="text" value="{{ person.location }}" placeholder="<?= __("Where do you live?"); ?>"></li>
  <li ng-repeat="person in person | filter: {id:1}"><textarea placeholder="<?= __("Write something about you..."); ?>">{{ person.summary }}</textarea></li>
</ol>
```

All the PHP function `__()` does is translate the given string. Anyway, as you can see I'm using the `ng-repeat` directive which I'd like to avoid as there's only one person and there will always be only one.

What I tried was using `ng-model="person"` in the `<ul>` element instead of `ng-repeat="person in person"` in every `<li>` and then try printing `{{ person.firstName }}` but nothing gets printed. But if I print `{{ person }}` I do get the whole object.

Well, I guess that pretty much sums up my problem. Thanks in advance for any input!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can't you do like this?:

```
$scope.person = data[0];
```

Comment: That's definitely part of it.  That should actually be sufficient to get around the need for the `ng-repeat` directive because then `$scope.person` would only contain the one person object instead of an array with one person object in it.  He will still need to set up his model bindings for the input fields correctly or the `person` info won't load into his form fields and his form entries won't be saved to his `person` model.

Comment: Yes! That does the trick! That and the HTML markup from @citizenslave 's answer (without the [0]).
Thank you. Both of you :-)

Comment: Yeah, the `[0]` here and the `[0]` in my markup are doing the same thing at different points.

Answer (score 2):

You don't use the `ng-model` directive when you're setting the content of an HTML tag.  `ng-model` is the Angular way to handle the `value` attribute in form fields.  For your purposes, you should be able to just write:

```
<ol ng-controller="PersonController">
  <li>
    <input data-autogrow name='firstName' ng-model='person[0].firstName'/>
    <input data-autogrow name='lastName' ng-model='person[0].lastName'/>
  </li>
  <li><input ng-model='person[0].headline'/></li>
  <li><input ng-model='person[0].location'/></li>
  <li><textarea ng-model='person[0].summary'/></li>
</ol>
```

Note, the `textarea` tag is not actually vanilla HTML, it's an [AngularJS directive](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive%3atextarea) implementing the same functionality, so it doesn't work in quite the same way and you can still bind the `ng-model` attribute instead of plugging it into the content as you would in vanilla HTML.

Answer (score 0):

You can not use same variable name 'person' for array and items in array. Your code should be

```
$scope.people = data;
```

Then in html

```
<li ng-repeat="person in people | filter: {id:1}">
```

Comment: Yeah, the `person in person` is not cool, but it does the trick. I mean, if I change that to `me in person` and then print the data using `{{ me.firstName }}` the result is still the same. 

However, what I'd like to do is stop using the `ng-repeat` directive and still be able to access the object.

Comment: The issue is with the code you're using to 'print' the data.  That's not how Angular model bindings work.

Comment: @Silvestre: What do you mean by stop using ng-repeat? Do you want to show multiple  people data or just single person's data? Usually id's are unique what is the point of using filter: {id:1} ?

Comment: @DeepakN yes, I wanted to use a single person's data (after all I only have one record on my database). That's why I used the filter to only show the element with the id "1". citizenslave is absolutely right, I misunderstood how Angular bindings work.